# Analytic continuation of Fredholm integral equations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, cv.complex-variables, singular-integral-equations

I am considering the equation of Fredholm type
$$
f(x) = \lambda \int_\zeta \prod(y-l_i(x))^{\alpha_i} f(y) dy\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
where

- $\zeta$ is an element of 1st homology of the complement to singularities of the integrand,
- $\alpha_i$ arbitrary complex numbers independent over reals,
- $l_i(x) = a_i x+b_i$, for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

I would like to analytically continue the solutions $f(x)$ into the complex plane.

Assume $\alpha_i$ are rationally independent.
The following lemmas are straightforward:

**Lemma 1**. The solutions equation \eqref{1} have singularities at the points
$$
x_{i_n,...,i_1} = l^{-1}_{i_n}\circ \ldots\circ l^{-1}_{i_1}(x_{i,j})
$$
where $x_{ij}$ are solutions of the system $l_i(x) = l_j(x)$ for $i\neq j$, $i,j = 1, \ldots , n$, $\circ$ denotes composition.

In general, these points are dense in complex plane. But

**Lemma 2**. On each branch of analyticity of the function $f(x)$, only finitely many points $x_i$ are visible at any finite distance $R$ from any given point.

In other words, one has to travel far in order to reach any point $x_i$.

**Corollary**. The function $f(x)$ defines a fiber bundle over a profinite Riemann surface that has the infinitely generated group

\begin{equation}
F_\infty = \langle g_i| \ldots\rangle 
\end{equation}

as its fundamental group.

**Question 1**: what are (if any ) the relations in this group?

**Question 2**: what representation of this group does $f(x)$ realize?

**Question 3**: is it possible to decompose the function in a natural direct sum of functions where the integral is over some suitably chosen simple contour?

With regard to Question 3 above, if the integrand is simply a product of linear factors $\prod(y-l'_a(x))^{\beta_i}$ ($\beta_i$ arbitrary complex numbers) then it is indeed so - it is reducible to loops that wind around a single point. This is also true in general, but the marked point of the loop is in this case on different sheets, and there is no way to relate function values on different sheets without additional considerations.

There probably are quite a lot of relations between generators that are satisfied by $f(x)$. For example

**Lemma 3**: Near each point $x_i$ the function $f_g(x)$ has expansion
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Reg}{\mathrm{Reg}}
f_g(x) = (x-x_i)^{\alpha_{i,g}} \Reg(x) + \Reg(x)
$$
where $\Reg(x)$ are some regular functions. The index $\alpha_{i,g}$ depends in general on the branch of analyticity.

**Lemma 4**. We have the following recursion relations
$$
\alpha_{i\cup\{i\};gg_i} = \alpha_{i,g}+\alpha_i+1
$$
if the contour $\zeta_g$ is such that it is trapped near $x$ and $x_{i,g}$, and is zero otherwise.

One can derive recursions on the coefficients of $\Reg(x)$ but they are long and I do not reproduce them here.

I obtained the above result as an exercise, and I could not find them in the literature. Nevertheless the literature on Fredholm equations is very large and it would be very naive to assume that the answers to the above questions, the characterization of the function $f(x)$ and the reformulation of the above integral equation in terms of Riemann-Hilbert problem are not known. I looked into books by Muskhelishvili, Mikhlin, Gripenberg & Londen and Staffens,  Tricomi, Vekua, Kress, Hochstadt, Gohberg and Krupnik and finally Corduneanu. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I have formatted your question a little in order to improve its readability: this is not my field of expertise so I am not able to answer. Nevertheless I would like to point out something I've not understand, possibly in order for you to improve the readability of your question and receive a good answer.
- What is the form of the contour $\zeta$?
- Could you add some informations on the exponents $\alpha_i$? For *rational independence* do you mean *independent over the rationals*?
- What's the meaning of operation $\circ$ in lemma 1? And how is defined $x_{ii}$ i.e. $x_{ij}$ when $i=j$?

Comment: And finally, what are the exponents $\beta_i$?